# Axios get request with web.php in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, axios

I am new to Axios and API. I was trying to get data from a table with laravel 8 and React js and it works fine with

```
const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/students');
```

When I try to do the same with

```
const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8081/web/students');
```

with web.php access, it shows the error in the console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/web/students' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/web/students net::ERR_FAILED 404.

Thanks.

Comment: you don't have to prefix the `web` in web routes like api routes. just use `const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8081/students');`

Comment: thanks for the reply. the same works ok with POSTMAN when I access it same error shows with GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/students net::ERR_FAILED 200

Answer (score 0):

As specified in `boot()` method in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`, web routes have no prefix.
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
Route::middleware('web')
   ->namespace($this->namespace)
   ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

So your endpoint should be `http://127.0.0.1:8081/students` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8081/web/students`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the same now the error is the same in the console with `GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/students net::ERR_FAILED 200`

Comment: are you using any middleware in web routes?

Comment: No. its the code in web.php `Route::get('students', [StudentDashboard::class, 'index']);`